# Metadata API Task.Subject translation

Tags: tasks, migration

I'm using ant for deployment, and have issue specifically with standard field on Task object - Subject.

When retrieving the taskTranslation (using eclipse IDE) the picklist values for this field are not added. All other standard/custom picklist values are there, except this field.
I added it manually in the XML and it worked during deployment, however anytime I'm refreshing the object file from SF , it deleting the translation section I added.

I'm trying to understand if it's issue in salesforce, or I'm doing something wrong.

I found in SF documentation:
"
Note: “Subject” on the Task object is a text field, not a picklist value. It can’t be retrieved via the Metadata API. Translations can be provided via the Translation Workbench."

However the filed type in setup/xml is picklist. Not clear in what it different from other picklist values in Task like Type or Status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone having this issue note that is was resolved in API 38/39 +.
In those APIs and above the standard picklist values translation stored in separated file:
e.g: TaskSubject-en_US

Therefore your options are either:
1.In API 37- Add the values manually in the task file
2.Upgrade the package.xml file to API 38 and above